# My Yii Application Saving and rules error

Tags: yii, save, rule

I've changed my codes a lot.

this is the code in my controller:

`public function actionRequestTV() {`

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/column1';
$this->bodyclass = 'bodygrey_without_leftbg';
$model = new Reqtv();

if (isset($_POST['Reqtv'])) {
    if ($model->validate()) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Reqtv'];
        if ($model->save()) 
            $this->redirect(array('step2', 'id' => $model->REQTVID));
    }
}elseif (isset($_POST['BP'])) {
    if ($model->validate()) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['BP'];
        if (!$model->save()) {
            print_r($model->getErrors());
        }else
            $this->redirect(array('step2B', 'id' => $model->REQTVID));
    }
}else
    $this->render('reqtvform_step1', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
```

}

here is the rules :

```
    public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('BPID, SK', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('BPMOBILE', 'numerical'),
            array('TVID, TVPASS', 'length', 'max' => 50),
            array('PROBLEM', 'length', 'max' => 250),
            array('BPCP, BPMOBILE, BPEMAIL', 'length', 'max' => 255),
            array('SK', 'ceksk'),
            array('BPEMAIL', 'email'),
            array('PSNO', 'cekPSNO'),
//            array('SK, PROBLEM, TVID, TVPASS', 'required', 'on' => 'step2'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('REQTVID, BPID, TVID, TVPASS, PROBLEM, SK, BPCP, BPMOBILE, BPEMAIL, PSNO', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }
```

after changing my code from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852791/why-my-controller-wont-save-the-value) into more simple like the code above, it already able to save the values. but, some rules doesn't work, like ceksk rule. this is the code of ceksk:

```
    public function ceksk() {
    if($this->SK){
    if (!$this->SK == 1) {
        $this->addError('SK', 'Maaf, anda harus mencentang persetujuan syarat & ketentuan sebelum melanjutkan');

        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

my ceksk rule is already work. but I'm decided to use JQuery instead:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('JQuery', "

  $('#kirim').click(function() {
if ($('#SK').attr('checked')) {
      return true;
      }else{
      alert('Anda belum mencentang Syarat & Ketentuan'); 
      return false;
    }
  });
");
?>
```

but my other rules still won't work. my cekPSNO rule is working actually. but when it catch the error, it bring me to a blank white page instead of staying in the form page and show the error. this is the code:

```
public function cekPSNO() {
        if ($this->PSNO) {
            $psno = Ps::model()->findByAttributes(array('PSNO' => $this->PSNO));

            //check cdsn ada atau tidak
            if ($psno === null) {
                $this->addError('PSNO', 'Nomor PS tidak ditemukan, silahkan periksa Nomor PS anda !');

                return false;
            } else {
                if (date('Y-m-d') > $psno->TGLBERAKHIR) {
                    $this->addError('PSNO', 'Premium Support sudah expired !');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please, your help are absolutely appreciated. thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function ceksk($attribute) {
    if (!$this->$attribute == 1)
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Maaf, anda harus mencentang persetujuan syarat & ketentuan sebelum melanjutkan');
}
```

source:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Comment: hi @whale_steward I already try it and it still doesn't work. just FYI, SK is a checkbox. thank you anyway :)

Comment: There is a typo in your solution. You missed a $ sign. `if(!$this->$attribute == 1)` instead of `if(!$this->attribute ==1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!$this->SK == 1)` is not going to produce the result you want.

Try with `if($this->SK != 1)`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

The negation from the `!` occurs before the comparison operator, which means you are effectively  executing `((!$this->SK) == 1)`.

This will cause the code block to never execute, for if `$this->SK` is present and can type type-juggled to true, then its negation will result on a `false` value, which when compared to `1` (a true value) is never true. Whereas if `$this->SK` is empty or type-juggles to false, the incorrect comparison later will never be executed, so your validation will never report failure.

Comment: hi @Willem Renzema, thank you for replying. I've tried your advice, but it still won't run. so, I decided to use JQuery instead:
`<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('JQuery', "
  $('#kirim').click(function() {
    if ($('#SK').attr('checked')) {
        return true;
      }else{
        alert('Anda belum mencentang Syarat & Ketentuan'); 
        return false;
        }
  });
");
?>`

but I still have problems with my other rules. they won't work at all. the cekPSNO rule is working, but when it got error, it stop in white blank page instead of stay in the form and show the error.

Comment: cekPSNO :
`public function cekPSNO() {
        if ($this->PSNO) {
            $psno = Ps::model()->findByAttributes(array('PSNO' => $this->PSNO));

            //check cdsn ada atau tidak
            if ($psno === null) {
                $this->addError('PSNO', 'Nomor PS tidak ditemukan, silahkan periksa Nomor PS anda !');

                return false;
            } else {
                if (date('Y-m-d') > $psno->TGLBERAKHIR) {
                    $this->addError('PSNO', 'Premium Support sudah expired !');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }`